# How taqdeer affects human in performing a deed(action)?

Tags: quran, deeds, soul, destiny

As per my understanding,

In a human body, Nafs & Ruh gets affected by following good(expected) & bad(mis-guided) path

عَقْل performs deed(actions) based on the combination of the inputs coming from   Nafs( نَفْس) and Ruh (  الروح ) depicted as shown below(based on my [documentation](https://github.com/shamhub/Islam/blob/main/purpose_of_life/Purpose_of_life.png)):

### [image]

---

How destiny(تقدیر) affects Nafs & Ruh in following of *good path* vs *mis-guided path*?

Any relevant verse in the Quran?